# How can i get the imageView's size from storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I add a imageView in storyboard, and add a few constraints(Trailing,Leading, Bottom, Top, Ratio).Now i want to get imageView size in code.

`NSlog("%f", cell.imageView.frame.size.width);`

But, when i run it in iPhone5, the result is the same as that run in iphone6.
what should i do , thank you very much(Xcode6, iOS sdks 8.1).

i have resolved it, when i moved the "cell.frame.size.width" to viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Where do you put this log?`viewDidLoad`?

Comment: If you have resolved it, you should accept the correct answer rather than posting answer in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autolayout Constraints are set after `viewDidLoad()`. So you should try to print in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or later in view controller lifecycle. Otherwise, you might have applied constraints (may be with respect to other views or as Nilesh states, equal width/height/aspect ratio) that force size to remain the same.

Comment: if the question is in the tableview cell, what should i do?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to ask. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have autolayout turned on (easiest way possible) and set constraints to the `imageView` that is in the `.storyboard` file. Look for this button in the bottom right corner of the standard editor when you are viewing the `.storyboard` file
[image]